# MySQL and Unity login

Tags: c#, mysql, unity-game-engine, ssh

I've just installed MySQL with phpmyadmin on my VPS via ssh protocol, and I've created root account with all privileges. I figured out how to connect with my databases via C# using MySQL 5.5v. for .Net 2.0 - the only version acceptable for Unity3D. And I have a few questions about it. I don't know is it right to connect to database on client side with root account, i mean something like that: `Server=***;Database=Users;Uid=root;Pwd=***;`
and then type query: `SELECT * FROM Users where ....` i think its unsafe way. How can I connect do it in more safety way? Without giving Password to Root account in C# code, maybe create another account without modify permissions?

Comment: you should never be using the root mysql account anyways. it's the sysadmin account. using it for day-to-day stuff is just asking for trouble. create new restricted accounts with ONLY the permissions they need to get their job done.

Comment: Maybe I should do it on server side and  as user send own query to TCP server and then execute SQL query via server and response user?

Comment: that's up to you. we're here to (maybe) help fix code, not design your system for you.

Comment: I know, but notice that in php, server do your work and you don't care about it, in tcp server its mixed. I just want to know, which way would be the best.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to connect to the database from the client(Unity), if this app will be released anywhere on the internet. The way to do this to use `POST` or `GET` method with the help of the [WWW](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) class, to send and receive information your server.

Your server should be coded with `php`,`perl`, `c++` or whatever language you prefer.It will read data you send from Unity, then retrieve information from database and send it back to the client(Unity). *Again, the whole database connection should be done on the server not on the client side*.

One exception to this is when your app will **only** be used in your company office. As long as it will be made available for others to download, it is **not** secure if you hard-code the login information or even allow direct connect to the database from the client side. There are many examples on Unity [wiki](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Server_Side_Highscores) website.

Comment: So... is it any sense to use mysql in these kinds of projects? I can do it with *.txt file with some data and just use them on server and give response to the client. Thank you for response. :)

Comment: **"is it any sense to use mysql in these kinds of projects?"** If you are going to be storing user information, files, and store data on the server, use Mysql. If you only need to store the file on a local driver, then use file.txt or whichever method you want.